# Pass JSON variable to AzureDevops Release definition

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My goal is to pass a JSON object from one machine to another using the AzureDevops pipeline variables.
The process starts with a powershell script that obtains the JSON object and compresses it to:

`$json=[{"test":"foo","bar":"hello}]`.

Please note that it will be always an array.
Now, I set the azure variable with:

`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Json]$json"`

now the variable is initialized in the release pipeline BUT, the double quotes are not escaped.
That means that when I try to obtain the `$(Json)` in the next script it fails due to invalid characters of course. My question is, how can escape those double quotes? I have tried adding single quotes to the beginning and the end of the string but it won't work. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing the closing quote after 'hello'.

Comment: How are you attempting to use ```$(Json)``` ?

Comment: Could add the error message to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the pipeline variable with a here-string before using it?

```
$json = @"
    $(Json)
"@
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following format for the JSON file:

```
$json = @"
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "Bug22"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity",
    "value": "3 - Medium"
  }
]
"@ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```